# DevExpress Refresh ASPxGridView automatically after update issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

Hi I am getting some issues regarding ASPxGridview. Below is my code where i can update records back to database with successfully.  But when i click on "Update" on edit form data save successfully but aspxgridview does not refresh automatically until i press F5 or page reload button. How can i reflect those changes without reload manually. Can i call javascript function on click of "EditFormUpdateButton". Please help me to overcome this problem.

```
[ASPx]
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onBindGridview(s, e) {
        GridView1.PerformCallback("Reload");
    }    
 </script>

<dx:ASPxGridView ID="GridView1" ClientInstanceName="GridView1" runat="server" KeyFieldName="DeptId" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"
    OnRowUpdating="Gridview1_RowUpdating" OnCustomCallback="gridView_CustomCallback">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowNewButtonInHeader="true" ShowEditButton="true" VisibleIndex="0" />
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="DeptName" Name="Department" VisibleIndex="1">
            <EditFormSettings VisibleIndex="0" />
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

    </Columns>

    <SettingsEditing>
        <BatchEditSettings EditMode="Row" />
    </SettingsEditing>

    <SettingsPopup>
        <EditForm Width="300" />
    </SettingsPopup>

 <Templates>
        <EditForm>               
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Department Name  :
                    </td>
                    <td>

                        <dx:ASPxTextBox runat="server" ID="edDeptName" Text='<%# Bind("DeptName") %>'>
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>                         
                    </td>
            </table>

              <div style="text-align: left; padding: 2px">
                      <dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="UpdateButton" ReplacementType="EditFormUpdateButton" 
                              runat="server" ></dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement>          
                      <dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="CancelButton" ReplacementType="EditFormCancelButton" 
                             runat="server"></dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement>
                 </div>             
        </EditForm>
    </Templates>
 </dx:ASPxGridView>
</asp:Content>
```

Code behind C# file

```
[C#]
 string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)   
    {          
        BindDeapartment();
    }
}

public void BindDeapartment()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "get_department";
    cmd.Connection = con;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}

protected void Gridview1_RowUpdating(object sender, ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "update_department";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeptId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.Keys["DeptId"]);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeptName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = e.NewValues["DeptName"];

    cmd.Connection = con;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        e.Cancel = true;
        GridView1.CancelEdit();
        GridView1.DataBind();


    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }

}


protected void gridView_CustomCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameters == "Reload")
    BindDeapartment();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when you do update your program go to `gridView_CustomCallback` but not enters inside if condition and doesn't executes `BindDeapartment()`.

So you have two options:

**ONE**

Remove if from `gridView_CustomCallback`:

```
protected void gridView_CustomCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
        {        
            BindDeapartment();
}
```

**TWO**

Add `BindDepartment()` to last line of `Gridview1_RowUpdating` file and remove `GridView1.DataBind();` because is not neccesary now:

```
 protected void Gridview1_RowUpdating(object sender, ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e)
    {

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "update_department";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeptId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.Keys["DeptId"]);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeptName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = e.NewValues["DeptName"];

cmd.Connection = con;

try
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    e.Cancel = true;
    GridView1.CancelEdit();
    BindDeapartment();


}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}

finally
{
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a business class for Department and as you are binding result set directly to grid, it is quite too complex(time performance) to fetch & bind again and again on every update.

```
GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

you can do like this

```
    Department objDepartment = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataSource = objDepartment;
```

So make a class for it and assign all the data to object of Department. Then set that object as datasource of grid.

For the case when you update any record, update the object as well when you are going to update values in database and rebind the grid with updated object. This will reduce multiple database hits.